# ZK - Tree not refreshing after data change

Tags: java, zk

I have a problem regarding model binding with the new tree binding mechanism of ZK6.
First, here's my code:

Zul:

```
<div id="win" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
viewModel="@id('vm') @init('mira.web.composer.PermissionDesignerModel')"
style="width:98%; text-align:center;" vflex="1">

<tree id="permissionTree" width="100%" model="@bind(vm.treeModel)"
    style="text-align:left;" vflex="2">
    <treecols>
        <treecol label="Item" width="400px" />
        <treecol label="Typ" />
        <treecol label="Ausgabe" />
        <treecol label="Einfügen" width="100px" />
    </treecols>
    <template name="model" var="node">
        <treeitem open="@bind(node.open)">
            <treerow>
                <treecell>
                    <textbox value="@bind(node.data.name)" />
                </treecell>
                <treecell>
                    <combobox mold="rounded" readonly="true"
                        model="@load(vm.allAttributeTypes)"
                        selectedIndex="@bind(node.data.attType)">
                        <template name="model">
                            <comboitem label="@load(each.name)"
                                value="@load(each.id)" />
                        </template>
                    </combobox>
                </treecell>
                <treecell>
                    <checkbox label="Ausgabe"
                        checked="@bind(node.data.isOutput)" />
                </treecell>
                <treecell>
                    <button label="Einfügen"
                        onClick="@command('insertNode', node=node)" />
                </treecell>
            </treerow>
        </treeitem>
    </template>
</tree>
```

The model:

```
public class PermissionDesignerModel {

ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("/beans.xml");
BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
private PermissionTreeModel treeModel;

@Command
public void insertNode(@BindingParam("node") PermissionTreeNode node) {
    node.setOpen(false);
}


public PermissionTreeModel getTreeModel() throws ParseException {
    if (treeModel == null) {
        PermissiontreeBuilder builder = new PermissiontreeBuilder(Container
                .getCurrentProduct().getProductId());
        PermissionTreeNode root = builder.getRoot();
        setTreeModel(new PermissionTreeModel(root));
    }
    return treeModel;
}

public void setTreeModel(PermissionTreeModel treeModel) {
    this.treeModel = treeModel;
}
```

}

The insertNode() method is called correctly, and I get the appropriate node with content in it, but when I change the data of the node (or the open-attribute), nothing happens in the UI. Do I have to call some special bind() method or something for the model-changes to take effect in the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer: you have to notify the UI for changes manually (for each variable).

```
@NotifyChange({ "treeModel" })
@Command
public void insertNode(@BindingParam("node") PermissionTreeNode node) {
    PermissionTreeNode addNode = node;
    if(node.getChildren() == null) {
        PermissionItem item = node.getData();
        PermissionTreeNode parent = (PermissionTreeNode) node.getParent();
        int index = parent.getIndex(node);
        parent.remove(node);
        addNode = new PermissionTreeNode(item, new ArrayList<PermissionTreeNode>());
        parent.insert(addNode, index);
    }
    addNode.add(new PermissionTreeNode(new PermissionItem()));
}
```

Where in NotifyChange you add the variables being changed within the method.